# symfony Form Event Subscriber $event->getData() return NULL

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I create formType class with no data_class:

```
$resolver->setDefaults(array(
        // 'data_class' => 'Mj\JobBundle\Entity\Ads', **i comment this**
 ));
```

first of all is it true?

and when i use event subscriber:

```
$builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function(FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            $data = $event->getData();
            $f = $event->getForm();
            var_dump($data);
            echo 'hii';
        }
    );
```

- $event->getData(); always return NULL
- if i uncomment  'data_class' it's works fine but i dont want so what should i do??

Comment: Forms need to know the underlying data type in order to create objects from field variables. This can either be guessed from the second argument to createForm() or can be specified with the data_class option. Can you give some information on why you don't want to pass the class of the underlying object to the form?

Comment: @Matt I have list of items and with this form user can filter items, but items not just come from one etity.   in general isn't there any way to use event->getData without using underlying data type??

Answer (score 2):

Because I did not watched out for the date of this question but I might clear things a little bit up for people having a similar issue.

Lets say you have a Form which contains some fields and you are using it without `data_class`. You can always preset data with second argument of the `createForm` function in the Controller. Example:

```
class TestType extends AbstractType {

        /**
         * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
         * @param array $options
         */
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

            // When passing a second argument to createForm you can get the data with $options['data']
            dump($options['data']);

            $builder
                ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event) {
                    // The $event will contain the preset data
                    dump($event->getData());
                })
                ->add('name', TextType::class)
                ->add('email', EmailType::class)
                ->add('message', TextareaType::class)
                ->add('send', SubmitType::class);
        }
    }
```

The data you pass the form to preset must be an array which keys represent the form field (e.g. `name`, `email`, `message`, `send`) and the value obviously is the value set to the form field. Example continued:

```
public function formTestAction(Request $request) {

    // These values will be preset and are accessible with
    // $event->getData() (inside an EventListener) OR
    // through $options['data'] inside the buildForm function
    $myPreSetData = array(
        'name'      => 'Peter Griffin',
        'email'     => 'redFireTrucks@family-guy.com',
        'message'   => 'The fire truck can consume 8 times his body weight.'
    );

    $form = $this->createForm(TestType::class, $myPreSetData);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        dump('finished');
        dump($form->getData());
        die();
    }

    return $this->render('@TestPra/Test/test_form.html.twig', array(
        'form'  => $form->createView()
    ));


}
```

---

But you might also want to have data in the form class which has nothing todo with the data represented by the form e.g. setting choices for a `ChoiceType` field. In this case you pass the data via the third argument of the `createForm` function:

In the Controller:

```
$fireTruckColorChoices = array(
    'red'   => 0,
    'ultraRed'   => 1
);

$form = $this->createForm(TestType::class, $myPreSetData, array(
    'fireTruckColorChoices' => $fireTruckColorChoices
));
```

Inside the `TestType` class you have to set the name of the passed option as required, in this case `fireTruckColorChoices`:

```
class TestType extends AbstractType {
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

        $builder
            ...
            ->add('fireTruckColor', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices'   => $options['fireTruckColorChoices'],
            ))
            ...;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        // Must be set
        $resolver->setRequired(array(
            'fireTruckColorChoices'
        ));
    }
}
```

---

You might also want to access data passed as options in an `EventListener` closure. In this case you just need to add a private variable to the form:

```
class TestType extends AbstractType {

    private $name;

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

        $this->name = $options['name'];

        $builder
            ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event) {
                dump($this->name);
            })
            ...;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setRequired(array(
            'name'
        ));
    }
}
```